# executing cmds on a Linux box from a windows box

Tags: linux, windows, opensuse, putty

How can I create a script on a windows box that retrieves data from the Linux box by executing cmds against the remote Linux box?

I have got putty and Plink on the win box but not sure how to fire the cmds from a script e.g. a bat file and get the results written back to a txt file on the win box.

How would I do this for something simple like a `grep` or `ls` cmd for example?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger the script on the Linux box without a login on that box or a cronjob that will run the script on the Linux box.

You can use cronjob to run the script, then export the result either to a network share or on a restricted web location (lock that web location to your IP).

Then you can use the .bat script in windows to parse the output from those locations.

Comment: i have a login of th elinux box. What i want to avoid is having to deploy any scripts to the Linux box. Any ideas what a grep cmd in a batch file would look like and how would it be triggered using plink?